# Elegant function to "increase" a JavaScript string - for example, turning "aac" into "aad"

Tags: javascript, strings

I'm writing a function to increase a string so, for example, "aac" becomes "aad" and "aaz" becomes "aba". The result is horribly inelegant, I can't get it simple enough and I feel I'm missing something. How to improve that code?

```
function inc_str(str){
    var str = str.split("").map(function(a){ return a.charCodeAt(0); });
    var n = 1;
    while (n<str.length){
        str[str.length-n]++;
        if (str[str.length-n] > "z".charCodeAt(0))
            str[str.length-n] = "a".charCodeAt(0),
            ++n;
        else
            break;
    };
    return str.map(function(a){ return String.fromCharCode(a); }).join("");
};
```

Extra points for a brief functional style solution! (Even if it needs to implement other functional functions such as zip or whatever.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A recursive approach is much more elegant in this case:

```
function inc_str(str) {
  var last = str[str.length - 1],
    head = str.substr(0, str.length - 1);
  if (last === "z") {
    return inc_str(head) + "a";
  } else {
    return head + String.fromCharCode(last.charCodeAt(0) + 1);
  }
}
```

Making it wrap around for `inc_str('z')` is left as an exercise for the reader (hint: `last` becomes `undefined`).

Comment: Hah! You couldn't resist opening an account just for this :)

Comment: Yay I'm glad I motivated someone to joining in. Great way to start, also. That was the obvious thing I was missing, recursion! Adapting from your answer, I got the one-liner: `function inc_str(str){ return (last(str) == "z") ? inc_str(head(str)) + "a" : head(str) + inc_char(last(str)); };` So elegant! Thank you.

Comment: @Dokkat you shouldn't write your code so condensed.

Comment: That's fine, this isn't meant to be human readable as it is the base of an AI programming system I'm developing. Less tokens = better and I must avoid varaibles.

Comment: @Dokkat, so you wrote it with your eyes closed?

Comment: @radarbob that's not the point, the system won't accept statements and variable definitions. Notice everything is an expression. This is analyzed by the AI. Are you curious to see it?

Comment: @Dokkat yes please

Comment: I'm finishing my work and will post it on Github probably by march 15, I've made a note to update you guys then!

Comment: Please note that the current implementation doesn't handle edge case properly. What do you want inc_str('z') to be for instance ?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this could be written as:

```
 function inc_str(str){
 return !/^[a-z0-9]$/i.test(str[str.length-1]) ? str :
         str.substr(0,str.length-1) + 
          ( /z/i.test(str[str.length-1]) 
            ? String.fromCharCode(str.charCodeAt(str.length-1)-25) 
            : String.fromCharCode(str.charCodeAt(str.length-1)+1))
}
// usage
inc_str('aaa'); //=> 'aab'
inc_str('aaz'); //=> 'aaa'
inc_str('aaZ'); //=> 'aaA'
inc_str('aa2'); //=> 'aa3'
```

Comment: Your code doesn't roll over. `inc_str('az')` outputs as "aa" but should be "ba"